# What is the "io_here" token in the Shell Command Language referring to?

Tags: bash, shell, command-line

In [Section 2.3 Token Recognition under Shell Command Language](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_03), what does the `io_here` token refer to?

> #### 2.3 Token Recognition
>
> The shell shall read its input in terms of lines. (For details about
>   how the shell reads its input, see the description of [*sh*](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sh.html#).) The
>   input lines can be of unlimited length. These lines shall be parsed
>   using two major modes: ordinary token recognition and processing of
>   here-documents.
>
> When an **io_here** token has been recognized by the grammar (see
>   [Shell
>   Grammar](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_10)),
>   one or more of the subsequent lines immediately following the next
>   **NEWLINE** token form the body of one or more here-documents and shall be parsed according to the rules of
>   [Here-Document](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_07_04).
>
> When it is not processing an **io_here**, the shell shall break its
>   input into tokens by applying the first applicable rule below to the
>   next character in its input. The token shall be from the current
>   position in the input until a token is delimited according to one of
>   the rules below; the characters forming the token are exactly those in
>   the input, including any quoting characters. If it is indicated that a
>   token is delimited, and no characters have been included in a token,
>   processing shall continue until an actual token is delimited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shell grammar defines **io_here** as

```
io_here          : DLESS     here_end
                 | DLESSDASH here_end
```

`DLESS` is `<<`, `DLESSDASH` is `<<-`, and **here_end** is the end-of-here-document marker.

So the **io_here** token is the token introducing a here-doc.